# How is the morphism of composition in the enriched category of modules constructed?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I asked this a week ago at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247222/how-is-the-morphism-of-composition-in-the-enriched-category-of-modules-construct), but without success.

I am studying enriched categories and I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong because all the way each step, each elementary proposition, requires enormous efforts and a lot of time from me. In particular, I am now stuck in the question of how the structure of the enriched category is introduced into the category $_AV$ of modules over a given monoid $A$ in a (symmetric) closed monoidal category $V$.

I asked this earlier (in April) at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121153/is-the-category-of-modules-over-an-abstract-monoid-enriched):

> if we consider an arbitrary closed monoidal category $V$ and take an arbitrary monoid $A$ in $V$, will the category $_A V$ of all [left $A$-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monoid) be an enriched category over $V$?

People explained to me the construction of the object of morphisms $V(M,N)$, I am grateful to them, and I accepted their answer, but not long ago I decided to write down the proof and (forgive me for my carelessness) I realized that I do not understand how the ["enriched" composition morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) is constructed in $_AV$:
$$
\circ_{L,M,N}:V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to V(L,N).
$$
I think that this must be the "lift to the equalizer" of the cone
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M,N)\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)
\end{equation}
for the pair of morphisms that define $V(L,N)$ as their equalizer:
$$
\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
$$
and
$$
\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L, \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,N)) \to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
$$
(here $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}$ means the inner hom-functor in $V$).
But the problem for me is that I don't understand why (1) is indeed a cone for this pair, i.e.

> why the two morphisms
> $$
> V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M,N)\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
> $$
> and
> $$
> V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M,N)\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L, \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,N)) \to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
> $$
> coincide.

My proof requires 40 diagrams, but this is only a draft, because I deduce everything from the following lemma, which still is a puzzle for me:

> **Lemma.** For each objects $A$, $X$, $Y$ and each morphism $\mu:A\otimes Y\to Y$ the following two morphisms coincide:
> $$
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X\to 
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,Y))\otimes A\otimes X\to 
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X\to Y
> $$
> (were the first arrow is generated by the arrow $Y\to\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,Y)$, which corresponds to the morphism $\mu:A\otimes Y\to Y$), and
> $$
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X\to 
> A\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,Y)\otimes X\to 
> A\otimes Y\to Y
> $$
> (were the last arrow is the morphism $\mu:A\otimes Y\to Y$).

This looks very strange to me (because it's difficult for me to believe that everything can be so complicated), but I don't see how this can be simplified, nor how to prove this lemma. Can anybody help me?

In Russia where I live, such problems are traditionally resolved by communication with experts, but as far as I know, there are no experts in category theory left in Russia.

Comment: Just a couple of meta-mathematical comments for the moment: 1. Proofs involving enriched categories often consist of "straightforward bookkeeping" but they can become annoyingly long, especially when your task is to prove that something *is* a V-category. 2. "there are no experts in category theory left in Russia" this reminds me of Hilbert's saying...

Comment: @fosco how do people prove this lemma?

Comment: The way you proposed is legitimate, and as far as I can see it does not require 30 diagrams, just four or five. I will try to sketch the idea below.

Comment: “In Russia where I live, such problems are traditionally resolved by communication with experts, but as far as I know, there are no experts in category theory left in Russia.”: Sergei Ivanov, Roman Mikhailov, Chris Brav, Alexander Pavlov, and many, many others…

Comment: @DmitriPavlov nobody of my friends recalled these people. Are they young? If they are available, I think I need their e-mail addresses, because there are many namesakes. I used to ask Vyacheslav Artamonov, but he died this summer.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: Sergei Ivanov: https://math-cs.spbu.ru/en/people/sergei-ivanov/, Roman Mikhailov: https://chebyshev.spbu.ru/en/people/roman-mikhailov/, Chris Brav: https://sites.google.com/view/chrisbrav/home, Alexander Pavlov: https://www.hse.ru/en/org/persons/224233362

Comment: @DmitriPavlov thank you. Now I found a kind person, Emily, who explains many things at another branch of MO:   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405172/tannaka-without-yoneda But I'll keep in mind these addresses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’ll change notation slightly, writing $\newcommand{\V}{\mathcal{V}}\V(A,B)$ and $\newcommand{\AV}{{}_{A}\! \V}\AV(M,N)$ respectively for the $\V$-hom-objects and $A$-module-homomorphism objects respectively.

The first thing I’d do is just write down the ordinary algebraic proof that a composition of module homomorphisms is a module homomorphism:
$$ (gf)(am) = g(f(am)) = g(a(fm)) = a(g(fm)) = a((gf)m).$$

This is very simple — just four steps! This makes me pretty confident that the categorical proof shouldn’t be *too* bad.  Generally, **a simple algebraic proof should become a reasonably simple categorical proof.**

So trying for the categorical proof: as you say, it comes down to showing that the map $$\newcommand{\x}{\otimes}\AV(M,N) \x \AV(N,P) \to \V(M,N) \x \V(N,P) \to \V(M,P)$$ equalises the two maps $\V(M,P) \to \V(A \x M, P)$ that define $\AV(M,P)$.  This means showing an equality of two maps $\AV(M,N) \x \AV(N,P) \to \V(A \x M,P)$; so it corresponds by transpose to an equality of maps $A \x M \x \AV(M,N) \x \AV(N,P) \to P$.

Now it’s ready for diagram-chasing: I wrote down the desired LHS as a vertical composite and worked rightwards from it until I could find the RHS.  Based on the algebraic proof above, I expected 4 main steps, in order: the definition of composition; the $(M,N)$ homomorphism condition; the $(N,P)$ homomorphism condition; and then the definition of composition again.  So I wrote those each down on the side to know what to look for.  Using those, together with the “interchange” rule $(\alpha \x B)(A' \x \beta) = (A \x \beta)(\alpha \x B')$, the following diagram pretty much wrote itself:

[image: big categorical diagram]

(although the layout was of course terrible the first time; this version is rewritten for readability).  Here the vertical composites down the left- and right-hand sides are exactly the maps $A \x M \x \AV(M,N) \x \AV(N,P) \to P$ we needed to show were equal.  Overall, as hoped, it really isn’t too bad in the end — one big diagram, built of 9 commutative squares/hexagons.

*Edit in response to comments:* Here I’m taking $\AV(M,N)$ to be defined as the equaliser of the maps $f_1, f_2 : \V(M,N) \to \V(A \x M, N)$ defined as the transposes of
$$\begin{align}
  \newcommand{\ev}{\mathrm{ev}}
g_1 & := \ev_{M,N}(\alpha_M \x \V(M,N)) : A \x M \x \V(M,N)\to M \x \V(M,N) \to N
\\ 
g_2 & := \alpha_N (A \x \ev_{M,N}) : A \x M \x \V(M,N) \to A \x N \to N.
\end{align}$$

With these definitions, no extra lemmas are needed for the proof above.  On the other hand, you say you’re using the definition given by Martin Brandenburg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4121259/2439), specifying the maps in the equaliser as

$$\begin{align}
 f_1' & := (\alpha_M)^* : \V(M,N) \to \V(A \x M,N) \\
 f_2' & := \chi (\bar{\alpha_N})_* : \V(M,N) \to \V(M,\V(A, N)) \to \V(A \x M, N)
\end{align}$$

Checking these agree with my $f_1$, $f_2$ depends slightly on which definitions you’re assuming for things like $(-)_*$ and the isomorphism $\chi : \V(M,\V(A, N)) \to \V(A \x M, N)$.  Under the definitions I’m used to, $f_1 = f_1'$ is automatic — “the transpose of $\ev_{M,N}(\alpha_M \x \V(M,N))$” is what I know as the standard definition for $(\alpha_M)^*$.  For $f_2 = f_2'$ — essentially the lemma you mention — it suffices to show that $f_2'$ corresponds under transpose to $g_2$. By definition (at least as I take it), $\chi$ corresponds to $\ev_{A,N}(A \x \ev_{M,\V(A,N)}) : A \x M \x \V(M,\V(A, N)) \to N$.  So $f_1' = \chi (\bar{\alpha_N})_*$ corresponds to
$$\begin{align}
  \ev_{A,N}(A \x \ev_{M,\V(A,N)})(A \x M \x (\bar{\alpha_N})_*)
& = \ev_{A,N}(A \x (\ev_{M,N}(M \x (\bar{\alpha_N})_*))) \\ 
& = \ev_{A,N}(A \x (\bar{\alpha_N} \ev_{M,N})) \\
& = \ev_{A,N}(A \x \bar{\alpha_N})(A\x \ev_{M,N}) \\
& = \alpha_N (A \x \ev_{M,N}) \\
& = g_2.\end{align}$$

Comment: > "a simple algebraic proof should become a reasonably simple categorical proof." It should, but there are notable exceptions : https://i.postimg.cc/3wFV3xyt/immagine-2021-09-19-122224.png

Comment: @fosco: Certainly — I meant it as a rule of thumb, not an absolute generality.

Comment: @fosco: Actually, working roughly through it, I don’t feel your linked exercise is really a counterexample — it feels like the ratio (size of algebraic proof):(size of categorical proof) is pretty typical, similar to this question.  Our familiarity with ring algebra makes the algebraic proof feel like a one-liner — but written out fully in terms of the (near-)ring axioms, it takes well over a dozen steps.  (The first approach I thought of used 26; with a little thought I’ve got it down to 18.)  So it’s not shocking that the categorical proof is long, especially if taken head-on.

Comment: Peter, I need some time to analyze this.

Comment: Peter, you are right with this big diagram, but those little fragments, that you mark by $\circledast$, are corollaries of my Lemma, isn't it? So I would think that this lemma is necessary anyway. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: It depends how you define the objects $\newcommand{\AV}{{}_A V}\AV(M,N)$ — in particular, how you give the maps $V(M,N) \to V(A \otimes M,N)$ for the equaliser.  I was assuming the definition where those maps are given as the transposes of the maps $A \otimes M \otimes V(M,N) \to N$ that appear in my ⊛ hexagons — so then the hexagons commute by definition.  I guess you’re following [Martin Brandenburg’s definition here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4121259/2439) — in that case, yes, you need to show his definition agrees with mine, which is roughly your lemma. (cont’d)

Comment: Peter, yes, I use the construction that Martin suggested at MSE. And I am stuck in the equivalence of these two definitions. How do people prove it?

Comment: I find the definition I used slightly simpler, so I recommend just taking it as primary, in which case you don’t need the lemma :-)  But yes, the two do coincide as your lemma says (and that takes just one fairly small diagram) — I can add more explanation later, when I have more time, if you’re still stuck on that.  It’s a good exercise with internal homs, though!

Comment: Peter, yes I would be grateful, if you could clarify this equivalence.

Comment: Peter, and your definition of $_AV(M,N)$ seems to be not independent: the existence of the universal morphism $_AV(M,N)\to V(M,N)$ such that the two ways from $A\otimes M\otimes {_AV(M,N)}$ to $N$ coincide, follows from Martin's construction... If I don't miss something. And again to prove this we need this Lemma.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: I’ve added a proof that my definition agrees with Martin’s definition you linked (which, as you say, amounts essentially to the lemma you give in the question).  But I don’t see what you mean that my definition is “not independent” — I think with the definition I give, everything in the main proof follows directly, not needing any mention of Martin’s definition?

Comment: Peter, thank you for this addition, and excuse me for not replying before, I was working. However I again need some time for translation so that I could understand this. I have a conjecture of what I am doing wrong: probably the whole point is that I do not write out chains of formulas, like you, but replace them with diagrams.

Comment: For example, in that big diagram that you gave, I would begin to prove the commutativity of each fragment by writing it out and completing it to a diagram whose fragments are commutative by the definition of a closed category (or have already been proved earlier). Could you resolve my doubts: is this the difference in our methods? Is it true that if we do this, then the original plan (like your big diagram) grows to a large number of diagrams? Or is our discrepancy in something else?

Comment: Actually, if you also could recommend a textbook for the beginners, that would be great. I do not see such a book.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: I recommend Kelly’s [Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html).  Regarding methods: I wouldn’t say the difference is diagrams vs. chains of formulas.  The big diagram shouldn’t expand much — the unmarked squares are just bifunctoriality of tensor.  And the was I think of this are, from most important to least, (1) algebraic/λ-calculus in the internal language, like at the start of my answer (for intuition, even if I’m not using it formally); (2) diagrams; (3) chains of formulas in the category itself.  [cont’d]

Comment: But the one tool I use constantly, which it seems you’re not so fluent with, is naturality of transpose, and in particular the co-unit formula for transpose.  Generally, for $\newcommand{\x}{\otimes}g\cdot f : A \to B \to [X,C]$, the transpose $\widehat{g\cdot f}$ is $\hat{g}\cdot (X \x f) : X \x A \to X \x B \to C$ — this is just naturality of the transpose operation.  Now taking $g = 1_{[X,C]}$ gives a general formula for the transpose: $\hat{f} = \widehat{1_{[X,C]}}\cdot (X \x f) : X \x A \to X \x [X,C] \to C$, and $\widehat{1_{[X,C]}}$ is $\mathrm{ev}_{X,C}$, the adjunction co-unit.

Comment: Peter, I would say, Kelly is not for beginners. After your words about different definitions, I checked them and I don't see differences betwen what I use and what Kelly and the websites write...

Comment: Peter, by the dot $g\cdot f$ do you mean the composition $g\circ f$?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: Yes, $\cdot$ is composition. In my note about definitions, I didn’t mean your definition was specifically different; just that a lot of concepts can be defined in several equivalent but slightly different ways — e.g. an adjunction can be defined in terms of natural bijections of hom-sets, or representability of the functors $C(X,U(-))$, or unit + counit + triangle equalities; similarly, the definition of monoidal closed category can be given several ways. You were asking me to break things down to “the axioms”; I didn’t know precisely which version of the axioms you wanted.

Comment: I see. OK, Peter, I need some time to look at all this, thank you!

Comment: Peter, I have another suspicion for the explanation of why your calculations are simpler: your connection between $-\otimes-$ and $V(-,-)$ is a bit unusual: $V(A\otimes M,N)=V(M,V(A,N))$. Not $V(A\otimes M,N)=V(A,V(M,N))$ as in Kelly's book and in the websites. Is this indeed important for simplification?

Answer (score 3):

$\def\mod{\text{Mod}}$Let's call $[X,Y]$ the internal hom of $X$ and $Y$, and $\mod_A(X,Y)$ the sub-$V$-object of $A$-module homomorphisms defined as the equaliser [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4121247/685).

Let $f : \mod_A(M,N)$ and $g : \mod_A(L,M)$, so that
$$
f \cdot \rho_M = \rho_N\cdot(A\otimes f)
\tag{If}$$
and
$$
g \cdot \rho_L = \rho_M \cdot(A\otimes g)
\tag{Ig}$$

Fact. The juxtaposition of two squares in a diagram

[image]

when precomposed with the map $\mod_A(M,N)\otimes \mod_A(L,M) \hookrightarrow [M,N]\otimes [L,M]$ at the top left corner, commutes.

Of course I have to tell you how the solid maps are defined:

- the leftmost and central solid vertical map is composition $c_{LMN}$ in the category $\mathscr{V}$; there is a universal way to obtain $c_{LMN}$ as mates of the maps that witness how hom functors are $\mathscr{V}$-functors
- the horizontal upper and lower pairs of maps are the pair of morphisms you equalise to obtain $\mod_A(M,N)$, $\mod_A(L,N)$, etc.
- careful: the lower row is an equaliser, but the upper one is not. It is, however, a cone.
- the rightmost vertical map arises from the map $M\cong I\otimes M \overset{e\otimes M}\to A\otimes M$, where $e$ is the unit of the monoid $A$ for which $M$ is a module.

A bit sloppily, this means that *if* we choose $(f,g)\in [M,N]\otimes [L,M]$ such that $f :  \mod_A(M,N)$ and $g : \mod_A(L,M)$, then chasing their image along the possible compositions in the above diagram yields the same result.

This is what you should prove in order to obtain that there is a unique dotted map
$$ \hat c_{LMN} : \mod_A(M,N)\otimes \mod_A(L,M) \to \mod_A(L,N) $$
making the left-most square commutative, and thus restricting the composition $c_{LMN} : [M,N]\otimes [L,M] \to [L, N]$.

It doesn't seem problematic to me to prove this statement; you just need the usual diagram chasing, plus (If) and (Ig) above.

A bit more effort is required if you want to show explicitly that the $\hat c_{LMN}$ "are compositions", in the sense that they are associative and unital. However, (again a bit sloppily) "they arise as restrictions of a composition rule".

Comment: Fosco, excuse me, what do those writings mean: $f:\operatorname{Mod}_A(M,N)$, $g:\operatorname{Mod}_A(L,M)$?

Comment: That $f : M \to N$ and $g : L \to M$ are $A$-module homomorphism; there, $:$ is just a shorthand for $\in$...

Comment: This style of explanation is unexpected for me, I don't understand something. When $V$ is an arbitrary monoidal closed category, the object $\operatorname{Mod}_A(M,N)$ does not necessarily consist of elements? What can $f\in\operatorname{Mod}_A(M,N)$ mean?

Comment: Perhaps, a morphism $f:I\to \operatorname{Mod}_A(M,N)$ (where $I$ is the unit object in $V$)?

Comment: Usually, in the absence of true elements, if $\#$ is an object, an element of $\#$ is a morphism $T \to \#$.

Comment: Where $T$ is the unit in $V$?

Comment: No, $T$ is a generic object of the category. If you show that a certain identity holds for every "element" in the above sense, the Yoneda lemma does the rest.

Comment: Fosco, "generic" means "arbitrary"?

Comment: Yes; it means that you fix $T$, and never mention it

Comment: Ah! Fosco, and by the Yoneda lemma do you mean the usual Yoneda lemma for the categories over sets, or the "enriched Yoneda lemma"?